# Access, Change all dates to Mondays

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

is there a quick way to nest an if (IIF?) in an UPDATE string to change all dates to the appropriate monday day of that week? So, if a date read TUESDAY 30 JULY, i would want it to be automatically updated to MONDAY 29 JULY. I figured an UPDATE TABLE, but unsure where to go from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need something similar to this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = fieldname-Weekday(fieldname,2)+1
```

`Weekday()` returns a number 1..7 indicating the day of the week. By default, 1 is Sunday. The argument 2 says to starting counting from Monday, so Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7.

So, for example, if the field's date is a Monday it subtracts 1 then adds 1, remaining Monday; if it's Tuesday it subtracts 2 (0) then adds 1 = 1, Monday.